# How to create windows task scheduler in Linux/Unix

Tags: cron

I have created a windows batch file script for checking a service & starting it if its in stopped mode than I mapped that script with Windows task scheduler to run in every 5 min with system privileges on that machine.

Below is the batch script.

```
@Echo Off
Set ServiceName=MYSERVICENAME

SC queryex "%ServiceName%"|Find "STATE"|Find /v "RUNNING">Nul&&(
   Net start "%ServiceName%">nul||(
         
        exit /b 1
    )

    exit /b 0
)||(
    exit /b 0
)
```

I dont have much knowledge on Linux/Unix however we can do this by creating some shell script & mapping that script with **crontab** hence I am looking some help here to create linux/unix script which look for a specific process & if its not running try restating it, also sometime process is not starting because of "**processname dead but subsys locked**" if we can also include that in script to handle and after that adding script to crontab for running in every 5 min.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemS.Tashkinov needed what you have shared seems very promising but I were reading the difference between crontab & systemd, as per article - Cron is guaranteed to be in any Unix-like system, in the sense of being an installable supported piece of software. That is not going to change. In contrast, systemd may or may not remain in Linux distributions in the future. It is mainly an init system, and may be replaced by a different init system.

Comment: Also I see there is one dependency with systemd process.service, its getting activated after reboot. Please help with any other script to start the process if its down due to xyz reason & that we can set somehow within cronjon

Comment: OK then, please help me with systemd, I created below systemd service start file but its not starting the service, is there anything wrong here- 

[Unit]
Description=Restart in case if its not running or crashed
After=network-online.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
User=root
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/besclient start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Status-
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/besclient.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2021-09-12 11:32:10 CDT; 10h ago